# How do I perform a muscle-up?

Tags: checo, muscle-ups

[Muscles-ups are an exercise](http://beastskills.com/tutorials/tutorials/53) where by we start of with a pull up and follow by a dip.

I have been trying to do that for the previous few months but am still unable to do it. I am able to do the pull-up but every time I want to change to dip I get stuck. Is there a way to train so that I can do that exercise?

Which muscle group is being use in doing muscle up?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may also want to check out this article on T-Nation about muscle ups:

- http://www.t-nation.com/free_online_article/most_recent/muscleups_the_ultimate_upper_body_exercise

The muscle up involves just about every muscle in the upper body.  Your entire back, your abs, every muscle in your arms, etc.  The video embedded in that article has a good approach to the progression needed.

One of the keys to being able to switch smoothly from pullup to dip is the false grip mentioned in the T-Nation article.  However, the following is a progression that can work:

- Train pull-ups and dips separately on a straight bar--using the false grip for both.  Be strict (no kipping).  Get to 15 at once on both.
- Train your pull-ups to get your chest touching the bar, and your dips down to touching your chest to the bar. Get to 15 at once on both.
- Use kipping to help with the transition from pull up to dip. Mental cue: "roll the bar". The bar won't move, but if you roll the bar toward your chest, it will help get your body into the dip position.
- Phase out the kipping and do them strict.

Comment: thanks alot. i will try to do a pull up to my chest for my next training. hoping that i can do a proper muscle up soon.